# Class 'HTML' not found in laravel 5 while using bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I was trying to add bootstrap to my laravel app but its not working properly.
while creating text area using bootstrap, i can see the text area but below text area its showing error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in bd4dbbba0de3e338e8b6884bcb514092774bce38.php line 21:
Class 'HTML' not found
in bd4dbbba0de3e338e8b6884bcb514092774bce38.php line 21
```

home.blade.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
        BloggerFramework    
    </title>



    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="article">Write something Awesome</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" cols="100" id="article"></textarea>
    </div>

    </body> 

    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
    {{ HTML::style('css/mystyle.css') }}

    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.ui.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}

</html>
```

can someone suggest any best practices for using front-end with laravel app

Comment: You need to include HTML  separately in Laravel 5 : https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/install-illuminatehtml-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Laravel 5 HTML and Form are removed from the framework and you need to install [Laravel HTML & Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation) manually.

If you've already installed this package, but you're still getting same error, try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_apps\App\bootstrap\app.php on line 14 showing errors i followed the steps

Comment: Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreatePasswordResetsTable" was found in bo
th "C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel_apps/App/database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_creat
e_password_resets_table.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel_apps/App/database/migr
ations/2016_04_17_072045_create_password_resets_table.php", the first will be us
ed. getting this while running composer update

Comment: For some reason you have two migrations with the same class name. Delete one of them.

Comment: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found now the textarea also gone

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto`

Comment: i run composer dumpauto but it's still showing the same error that "Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found"

Comment: This happens. Try to comment added lines in `config/app.php` (all Laravel Collective lines), save the file, run `composer update`, uncomment these lines and run 'composer dumpauto'.

Comment: while installing laravelcollective it's showing  '- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel
/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9]. '

Comment: ` and while executing php artisan serve i am getting <code>PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xamp
p\htdocs\Laravel_apps\Blogger\bootstrap\app.php on line 14 `

Comment: I think its installed correctly but stll the webpage showing html not found on above home.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5* Framework has removed the Inbuild FORM And HTML support.

Install Laravel Collective package for Form And Html Support.

If it is already installed then use **Html** instead of **HTML**.

If Not then follow the below steps:

**composer require laravelcollective/html**

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

**'providers' => [Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,],**

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

**'aliases' => ['Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,],**

Example :  https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Comment: Thanks, its working but can u tell any best documentation for learning about using front end with laravel 5